# why are the values of props recognised despite `props` not being used

Tags: vuejs3, lint, vue-props

I have a very simple vuejs component like this :

```
<template>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</template>
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  title: String,
})
</script>
```

`title` is correctly interpreted to the prop being passed to this component. Out of curiosity: why do I not need to do `{{props.title}}` for this to work.

This only reason I now write `{{props.title}}` is in order to do away with lint errors.

Comment: What I know is you don't have to use like `props.title` . You can access the props property in the template by default. But in the script tag you have use like `props.title` to access the props property

Comment: If you are facing the linting error when doing `{{title}}`, maybe your IDE is configured wrong. If you are using vscode, try to use [Volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar)